# Is there a way to call an alert controller from inside a current alert controller (or a textfield in an action sheet)? Xcode 8, Swift 3, IOS

Tags: ios, swift3, uialertcontroller, uiactionsheet

Please help! Im a huge beginner. Im trying to get a [picker view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrKVh.jpg) and [a textfield into one alert controller.](https://ashfurrow.com/img/import/blog/uialertviewcontroller-example/9EA0E4E86AB54891A9A27BC24D1C8889.png) Apparently I can't add a picker view into an alert controller since IOS 8. Instead I need to use an [action sheet with multiple actions](http://nshipster.s3.amazonaws.com/uialertcontroller-alert-one-two-three-cancel.png). Why can't I use a [default alert style?](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-2IodMok_B1w/VtcsjhFX7aI/AAAAAAAAATk/9ahEt8X3yeA/s1600/simple.png) Because I need more than 2 actions and the default alert style apparently only permits a max of 2 actions. So, I need to use an action sheet. Only problem is I can't seem to find a way to put an [editable textfield](https://ashfurrow.com/img/import/blog/uialertviewcontroller-example/9EA0E4E86AB54891A9A27BC24D1C8889.png) into [an action sheet,](http://nshipster.s3.amazonaws.com/uialertcontroller-alert-one-two-three-cancel.png) to have multiple action options - instead of [an editable textfield in my default alert style,](https://ashfurrow.com/img/import/blog/uialertviewcontroller-example/9EA0E4E86AB54891A9A27BC24D1C8889.png) with only two action options.

This is what I have so far, for my [editable textfield in my default alert style, with only two options (OK and cancel):](https://ashfurrow.com/img/import/blog/uialertviewcontroller-example/9EA0E4E86AB54891A9A27BC24D1C8889.png)

```
@IBOutlet weak var TEXTTESTLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func TEXTESTTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("TEXTTEST Button Tapped")
    openTEXTTESTAlert()
}


func openTEXTTESTAlert() {
    //Create Alert Controller
    let alert9 = UIAlertController (title: "Test Your Text:", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    //Create Cancel Action
    let cancel9 = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)

    alert9.addAction(cancel9)

    //Create OK Action
    let ok9 = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (action: UIAlertAction) in print("OK")
        let textfield = alert9.textFields?[0]
        print(textfield?.text!)
        self.TEXTTESTLabel.text = textfield?.text!
    }

    alert9.addAction(ok9)

    //Add Text Field
    alert9.addTextField { (textfield: UITextField) in
        textfield.placeholder = "TEXTTEST"
    }

    //Present Alert Controller
    self.present(alert9, animated:true, completion: nil)
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Since this, I've gotten help to create two separate alert controllers but it looks and feels messy. It's set up so if I click button 2 [the default alert style with a textfield will pop](https://ashfurrow.com/img/import/blog/uialertviewcontroller-example/9EA0E4E86AB54891A9A27BC24D1C8889.png) and insert text into a label. But, if i click button 1, AND THEN I click button 2, it will show [an action sheet with 4 actions](http://nshipster.s3.amazonaws.com/uialertcontroller-alert-one-two-three-cancel.png) that put a word into that same label. This is what I have for that method:

```
@IBOutlet weak var TextLabel: UILabel!


var userWantsToShowAlert = false

@IBAction func yourNewButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    userWantsToShowAlert = !userWantsToShowAlert
    print("User wants to show alert? \(userWantsToShowAlert)")
    //This is userWantsToShowAlert is false, it will change it to true. And if it is true, it will change it to false.
}

@IBAction func TextButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("Text Button Tapped")
    if(userWantsToShowAlert){
        openTextAlert()
    }else{
        openActionSheetAlert()
    }


}

func openTextAlert() {
    //Create Alert Controller
    let alert9 = UIAlertController (title: "Whatever Text Your Heart Desires:", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    //Create Cancel Action
    let cancel9 = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)

    alert9.addAction(cancel9)

    //Create OK Action
    let ok9 = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (action: UIAlertAction) in print("OK")
        let textfield = alert9.textFields?[0]
        print(textfield?.text!)
        self.TextLabel.text = textfield?.text!
    }

    alert9.addAction(ok9)

    //Add Text Field
    alert9.addTextField { (textfield: UITextField) in
        textfield.placeholder = "Whatever text you want to enter"
    }

    //Present Alert Controller
    self.present(alert9, animated:true, completion: nil)
}

func openActionSheetAlert(){
    let alert9 = UIAlertController (title: "Whatever Text Your Heart Desires:", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet)

    //Create Cancel Action
    let cancel9 = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)
    alert9.addAction(cancel9)


    let bt1 = UIAlertAction(title: "1", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){
        (action) in self.TextLabel.text = "Word 1"}

    alert9.addAction(bt1)

    let bt2 = UIAlertAction(title: "2", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){
        (action) in self.TextLabel.text = "Word 2"}

    alert9.addAction(bt2)


    let bt3 = UIAlertAction(title: "3", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){
        (action) in self.TextLabel.text = "Word 3"}

    alert9.addAction(bt3)

    let bt4 = UIAlertAction(title: "4", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){
        (action) in self.TextLabel.text = "Word 4"}
    alert9.addAction(bt4)

    alert9.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    alert9.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.size.width / 2.0, y: self.view.bounds.size.height / 4.0, width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
    self.present(alert9, animated:true, completion: nil)
}
```

I find that this method is confusing to the application user. If anyone has a different method to get a textfield into an action sheet (or even a separate alert controller imbedded in a current alert controller), I'd appreciate it VERY much! 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! I was wrong about having only 2 actions in the default alert style. [How to scroll through actions in alert controller? Xcode 8, Swift 3, IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42423698/how-to-scroll-through-actions-in-alert-controller-xcode-8-swift-3-ios)

Answer (score 0):

For Action sheet you can use as

```
   func showActionSheet() 
  {
    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet)

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "1:", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (alert:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
       )
         self.action1()
    }))

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "2", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (alert:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        self.action2()
    }))

  actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "3", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (alert:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        // self.action3()
    }))


    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil))

     self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

  // showActionSheet()
```